# How to convert list of tuples to dictionary with index as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

I’m trying to convert a list of tuples to a dictionary with the index of the list as its key.

```
m = [(1, 'Sports', 222), 
     (2, 'Tools', 11),
     (3, 'Clothing', 23)]
```

So far, I’ve tried using:

```
dict((i:{a,b,c}) for a,b,c in enumerate(m))
```

but this is not working.

My expected output is:

```
{0: [1, 'Sports', 222],
 1: [2, 'Tools', 11],
 2: [3, 'Clothing', 23]}
```

Comment: `... for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(m)` would work, but unpacking the tuple only to pack the three items again is unnecessary.

Comment: Note that there is not much sense in doing this conversion as the original list you have offers pretty much the same functionality (the items' keys are their indexes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {i:list(t) for i, t in enumerate(m)}
{0: [1, 'Sports', 222], 1: [2, 'Tools', 11], 2: [3, 'Clothing', 23]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll work

```
tuple_list = [(1, 'Sports', 222), (2, 'Tools', 11), (3, 'Clothing', 23)]

output_dict = {}
for index, data in enumerate(tuple_list):
    output_dict[index] = list(data)

print(output_dict)
```